# Real and Imaginary parts

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone help me finding the real and the imaginary part of the function $f(x)=\cot(x+i)$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$?

**EDIT: $x\in \mathbb R$.**

Comment: Did you try WolframAlpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cot%28x%2Bi%29

Comment: You don't say whether $x$ is supposed to be real.

Comment: @tards: That was amazing! I didn't know about wolframalpha, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If $x\in \mathbb R$, then you should be able to use the definition of complex sine and cosine, and then multiply both the numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate.

$$\begin{align*}\cot(x+i) &= \frac{\cos(x+i)}{\sin(x+i)}\\
&=\frac{\cos x \cosh 1 -i\sin x \sinh 1}{\sin x \cosh 1 + i \cos x \sinh 1}\end{align*}$$
... and so on. Related:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Relationship_to_exponential_function_and_complex_numbers